# How to define different permissions on a repository dependent on the SSH key on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, ssh, permissions, repository

I have an account on GitHub and use it for both my private projects and also for working on projects of multiple [organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations).

Now I want to checkout a organisation's private repository on the server.
To do that I need an SSH key there.

I could copy my private key to the server, but it's a very bad idea... Another way is to create a fake/bot GitHub account ([machine user](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users)), that would only be used for pulling the code to the server. OK, but it still look like a workaround.

A clean way would be to create a new private key, then a plublic key for it, add it to GitHub, and then restrict the permissions of the user, that connects to GitHub with this key (this user should e.g. only be able to pull from the repositories X and Y of the organization Z).

Is it possible on GitHub? 
**How can I define permissions on GitHub repositories dependent on the SSH key?**

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your problem. If s/o wants to add you with read access to a repo, they should add you and grant your read permissions only.
If you want to grant another person read access to one of your repo, add that person's or company's account and grant read access only.

Comment: Thank for your comment! What i want is to be able to (at least) pull the code from the repo on GitHub to the server without creating a [machine user](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users) for the server.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I guess for that problem the solution is to actually do just that: creating a machine user (that's what I do at least).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: You can't.

Explaining the answer has more to do with security and permissions management than Git itself.

If you take a step back and look at the authentication/authorization chain you will understand why.

You have a GitHub account, *MyGitHubAccount*. To authenticate yourself via the web portal, you use your username and password credentials. To authenticate yourself via Git+SSH, you use your SSH key.
That's what the key is: A secret credential that allows GitHub to recognize you as the user of *MyGitHubAccount*. Once you are authenticated as *MyGitHubAccount*, GitHub will check if you are allowed to read/write from the repository.
That's the account that has read/write permissions.

So if you wish to use different permissions, you need to create another account. That's the way you would do it on any other system so I don't see why this would seem like a bad solution.

The sole purpose of the SSH key is to identify the user. The reason why you can have several keys is that you should not be copying your keys around, but rather create a new key on each computer you want to connect to GitHub from. That way, you can revoke the key corresponding to one specific computer if it was, for example, stolen or tampered with.